# How do we call a region of low carrying capacity?

Tags: ecology, population-biology, definitions

I am looking for a convenient word to define a region of the landscape where the  local carrying capacity (population size) for a given species is low but different from zero. The species is still present in this zone.

How would you call such area?

Comment: I hesitated to ask my question here or on [ELL.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I asked my question here as I am hoping that there is a term in used in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask about quantity/numbers only, I would suggest using "the zone of low population density" or "**intermittent zone**" which in turn borders the "buffer zone" and "the zone of intermediate/high population density".

The "buffer zone" is the zone between two different populations where the number of the animals in question is zero.

J.Potts, M.Lewis "[How do animal territories form and change? Lessons from 20 years of mechanistic modelling](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/281/1784/20140231)"

There are other classifications based on the "main usage" of the territories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Reading your answer I reazized my question was unclear. I meant a zone of low carrying capacity surrounded by zones of high carrying capacity. I edited my post. Your answer seemed very correct as one possible interpretation of my previously answered question. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @Remi.b IMHO, you should roll back to your original formulation and use ADD word (or UPD) before a new part of the question. I answered the original question, now you ask another question (which is obscure as well), so the answer looks not relevant...

Comment: I rolled back to my previously unclear question. I'll open a new post (or just ask my colleagues) for the question I really wanted to ask. Thank you. +1 Btw, what does "ADD" and "UPD" mean?